# What's xmlns:mstns in a XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

What do the xml:mstns express in the following xsd-header?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="config"
    targetNamespace="http:/tempuri.org/config.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns=""
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/config.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="config">
...
```

Comment: It defines an XML namespace `"http://tempuri.org/config.xsd"` and assigns it a prefix of `mstns`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's an XML namespace declaration.

XML namespaces are really defined by URIs, so that a qualified name consists of a namespace (an arbitrary URI) and a local name (a short simple string following the NCName rules). However, that can't be written out in full every time, so namespaces are mapped to prefixes by a namespace declaration, which always takes the form of an attribute starting with `xmlns` and which defines that prefix for the element containing it and all its child elements.

Let's take your case as an example.

We have an attribute `xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/config.xsd"`, and that simply says that the prefix `mstns` is mapped to the namespace URI `http://tempuri.org/config.xsd`; this means that all elements and attributes whose names start with `mstns:` (note the colon) are in that namespace. In your example we also see `xmlns=""`, which maps all elements (tricky point: not attributes!) without prefix to the empty URI.

Obviously, you can't use `xmlns` itself as a prefix (it's magical) and in fact all prefixes starting with `xml` are reserved. There's a common habit of using the `tns` prefix in schemas to indicate the Target NameSpace.

Comment: Prefixes are arbitrary names (no colons, usual XML basic name rules).

Comment: And what about this exact namespace (mstns)? Does it have any special meaning in Visual Studio or .NET ? (It's declared by default in all schema files created in Visual Studio.)

Comment: @kubal5003: The `mstns` _prefix_ has, to my knowledge, no special meaning. Prefixes are arbitrary (well, they're arbitrary NCNames in XML parlance). VS might assign special meaning to it I suppose, but probably not; Microsoft's tools have a habit of putting “ms” in all sorts of arbitrary generated names. (The URI that is the actual _logical name_ of the namespace can have all sorts of semantics associated with it, but I don't think you're asking about that.)

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, “mstns” is the prefix “ms” (gee, MicroSoft loves to get in there somewhere!) followed by “tns” which normally stands for “target namespace”, which is the namespace in which you're declaring elements. In other words, it really doesn't mean very much in itself…

Answer (score 2):

It is just a XML namespace. It is used as a prefix before tags. I guess the mstns is added by Microsoft's XML Serializer.