# Does xmlns:mstns in an XSD imply it was generated from a C# class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have received an XSD schema that starts with (actual values replaced with `...`):

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="..."
           elementFormDefault="..."
           xmlns="..."
           xmlns:mstns="..."
           xmlns:xs="...">
```

Does the presence of `xmlns:mstns` mean that this XSD was generated from a C# class using xsd.exe? Question [What's xmlns:mstns in a XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027265/whats-xmlnsmstns-in-a-xsd) implies that it is added from `XmlSerializer`, and I know [you can create an XSD from a C# class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017139/how-to-create-a-xsd-schema-from-a-class).

Comment: No.  xsd.exe will take any schema and produce classes.  Having xmlns:mstns means the schema uses the additional schema found at the msdn website.

Comment: Is there a reason you're asking? The XSD shown in the second question you linked to doesn't have `xmlnd:mstns` in it.

Comment: @jdweng I'm talking about [creating an XSD from C# classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10017422/492336), not about creating C# classes from an XSD. Also the URL inside the mstns doesn't point to an msdn website - actually it has the same value as xmlns attrib.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks, I hadn't noticed the output is provided. So the generated XSD wouldn't have mstns.